# Is there any mistake in the CURL request I'm making?

Tags: php, json, curl, request

Is there any mistake in the CURL request I'm making from the terminal on my Linux machine?

```
curl -H 'token: 90006c4d3a0baba0677bc592ba6d8e6ae25e1b5589c0570904c217fcc5cf7aea' -X POST -d '
{
   "photo":[
      {
         "fileURL":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/UYUkZVHERGufB0enRbJo",
         "filename":"IMG_0004.JPG"
      },
      {
         "fileURL":"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/WZeQAR4zRJaPyW6hDcza",
         "filename":"IMG_0003.JPG"
      }
   ],
   "status_info":"WS test status for Photo",
   "group_id":181
}' http://54.174.50.242/api/feed/addPhotos
```

The request must be in valid JSON format. Is there any issue with the JSON validation or any other issue?
Please help me.

Comment: Why not find out by executing it?

Comment: does it work? if not, what errors are you getting?  according to [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/) the json is valid.

Comment: do you get any erro?

Answer (score -1):

```
yes it's fine. but i think you should use it after make array.

    enter code here


{
  "array": [
    {
      "photo": [
        {
          "fileURL": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/UYUkZVHERGufB0enRbJo",
          "filename": "IMG_0004.JPG"
        },
        {
          "fileURL": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/WZeQAR4zRJaPyW6hDcza",
          "filename": "IMG_0003.JPG"
        }
      ],
      "status_info": "WS test status for Photo",
      "group_id": 181
    }
  ]
}
```